# I want to texture a model from Total War: Warhammer 3

Tags: materials, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to texture a Soul Grinder from Total War: Warhammer 3 but the bottom half of it is giving a weird shading issue. I'm not at all good with fixing up textures in Blender so I've been relying on others this far but it hasn't really gotten me anywhere so if someone could help me figure out the issue I'd really appreciate it

[image: Weird lighting][image: A weird cut off on the texture]

[The Model Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VSI91kshR3iGoGy9aIWyLXCBE6EslaWZ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are already questions about the same problem.

**(1)** Disable the *Auto Smooth* option. **(2)** It uses the *Custom Split Normals Data*. Imported models often have this data and it causes shading issues in Blender. You can delete it if you don't need it outside of Blender.

[image: screenshot 1]

**(3)** The *Image Texture* nodes for all maps and masks (*Normal, Metallic, Roughness*, etc) should have set *Color Space* to `Non-Color`. Only set *Base Color* to `sRGB`.

[image: screenshot 2]